# targetFramework="4.0" is said to be optional but my website fails to build without it

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Even though targetFramework="4.0" is said to be optional and default to IIS website settings if not mentioned but my website fails to build, gets confused on the System dll version, seems to reference older one's I checked the references everything added is 4.0 yet i get errors on Linq and lambda expressions indicating it is actually not targetting 4.0 without that setting in web.config, any idea?

Comment: What version of IIS you are using ?

Comment: IIS 7, Windows Server 2008

Comment: What is you pipeline mode of the pool ? DId you configure pool for .Net 4 ?

Comment: Yes the pool is configured to .NET Framework v4.0.30319 and Classic and enabled 32-bit